# Can access event.target, which has a value attribute, but event.target.value always returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. This is absolutely baffling me. I can access the HTML element using event.target, and it shows value equal to some number, but every time I use event.target.value, I get undefined.

I've tried copying other code. I've tried Googling and searching Stack Overflow. I've tried using currentTarget instead of target and get the exact same results. This is extremely simple stuff; what is happening?.

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input : "0"
    }
    this.handleNumber = this.handleNumber.bind(this);
  }

  handleNumber(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target);
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="calculatorLayout">
        <div id="display">{this.state.input}</div>
        <div className="calculatorButtons" id="zero" value="0" onClick={this.handleNumber}>0</div>
        <div className="calculatorButtons" id="one" value="1" onClick={this.handleNumber}>1</div>
        <div className="calculatorButtons" id="two" value="2" onClick={this.handleNumber}>2</div>
```

...etc.

I expect to get numbers when I access event.target.value, but every time I get undefined.

event.target returns:

```
<div class="calculatorButtons" id="zero" value="0">0</div>
```

event.target.value of the same element returns:

```
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use `event.target.getAttribute("value")` for non-`<input>` elements.

Comment: Thank you so much, add as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.value` *property* on DOM nodes is only for things like `<input>` or `<textarea>`.  For other elements (like your `<div>`), you have to fetch the value via `.getAttribute()`. Thus

```
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute("value"));
```

should do what you're asking.